Problem reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 due to missing Reinstall Ubuntu option
I need to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04. The problem is that in the Install panel -> Installation type screens the Reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 LTS option is not present. There are only the Next options.
I have used ubuntu-22.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso, and prepared the USB
with Rufus 4.5. Please provide any suggestions to solve this problem as I need to reinstall Ubuntu without erasing my files.
